# Wild Card Character in copy utility Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have been facing issues while doing a copy from one fileshare to filesystem in azure data factory

FileNames are like below

Files_230606_**737363**.txt ,
Files_220606_**627277**.txt ,
Files_210606_**737688**.txt ,
Files_200606_**101010**.txt

The first part after Files is today's date in yyMMdd and 2nd bold part is random number

The File is copied everyday from one location to another.

To locate the file i am using dynamic expression in dataSet as below

@concat('FIles_', formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(), -1), 'yyMMdd'),'*.txt')

I have been facing issue when i use * as wildcard

the error shows Files_200606_* can not be found

Is anyone having faced the same situation please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Add your dynamic expression in wildcard filename as below.

```
@concat('Files_', formatDateTime(addDays(utcNow(), -1), 'yyMMdd'),'*.txt')
```

[image]

Below is the wildcard filename

[image]

Output:

[image]

Input file:

[image]

Output written:

[image]